# Differentiability of signed distance function to hypersurfaces without compactness

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and the boundary $M = \partial U$ is a $C^2$-manifold. Let $\delta$ be the signed distance to $M$.

May I ask under what conditions, without assuming compactness, I can guarantee there exists a uniformly large neighborhood of $M$ for which $\delta\in C^2$.

 [Regularity of the Distance Function](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-092-01/S0002-9939-1984-0749908-9/S0002-9939-1984-0749908-9.pdf)

 [Distance to $C^k$-hypersurfaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039681900139)

In particular, if $n(y)$ is the outward unit normal vector, does assuming a bound on $\partial_y n$ suffices? Thank you.

Comment: Take $U = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $M= \{z=0\} \cup \{z=\epsilon\}$. You cannot obtain a uniform such estimate as $\epsilon\to 0$ (the distance function is not $C^2$ at $z=\epsilon/2$).

Comment: Thank you, but I want to fix $M$. So, given this particular $M$, can I find a uniform $\epsilon>0$ such that the signed distance is $C^2$ for all $y\in \{z:d(z,M) <\epsilon\}$?

Comment: you can do something similar where two sheets of M get close together near infinity. Or e.g a spiraling curve.